# Managing git Bitbucket repositories- deleted files should not re-appear on download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, bitbucket

I am currently working on a Ruby on Rails repository where the folder structure is pretty complex, and i often need to restructure the files (for example moving js files and css files from folderA to assets folderB and in many cases integration of file A and file B into file A, and I delete file B in my local).

I notice that git and bitbucket by default does handle versions by incrementally maintaining changes to the existing and new files while still maintaining the older files and folders under earlier commits.

As a result, when I download the entire rails repository from bitbucket at a later stage, I get a very complicated and structure of files and folders that is not representative of my latest repository structure as it contains earlier versions of files that have been deleted or moved. (in the case above, file B still appears on the download)

How do I ensure that my directory structures and files are representative exactly of what i have saved down as my latest version and do not include prior deleted files.

Comment: When you've moved files/folders, how have you told git that you have done this?

Comment: I "git add ." and "git commit" entire folder structures.

Comment: When moving files you must do so using git mv if you wish git to keep proper account of their correct locations.